# strings and longs and classes as properties

Tags: c#, properties

im currently trying to learn about properties and i understand the benefit of using them but i dont know how to handle Classes in class.

Se example

```
public class Office
{

    public long Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public long EmployesCount { get; set; }

    public Rooms Rooms
    {
        get { return _rooms; }
        set { _rooms = value; }
    }

    private Rooms _rooms = new Rooms();
}

public class Rooms
{
    public long Identifier { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    //and so on
}
```

if i dont set the private Rooms to new i'll get nullreference exeception. so is this good practice or should i just declare the rooms class like this instead.

```
public Rooms Rooms = new Rooms();
```

is there a point to make the class "Rooms" as property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All non-static classes need to be set to an instance of an object, somewhere, if you want to call methods against that object.

Depends on who you want to initialize that object. If you want whoever is using your class to do it, just leave as:

```
public Rooms Rooms {get;set;}
```

Then someone can do:

```
Office o = new Office();
o.Rooms = new Rooms();
```

If you want to make sure Rooms is never null, just initialize it in your Office constructor:

```
public Office() {
  this.Rooms = new Rooms();
}

public Rooms Rooms {get;set;}
```

In the above case, we can use:

```
Office o = new Office();
// Rooms will be initialized when we first use it
o.Rooms.Length = 15;
```

Comment: @knittl Never even considered that. Updated to add logic to constructor. Would adding a lock to the get/set make the previous thread-safe?

Comment: @Knittl what is not thread-safe? is your answer below thread-safe?

Comment: @Dendei Previously my code for initializing inside a property was not thread-safe. Both above solutions (and also knittl's below which is the same as my second solution) are thread-safe

Comment: @RGraham Ok, thank you. i think i understand now i'll have to read more about properties to understand the benefit of using classes as properties but... i understand with normal strings or ints that you might want to change or limit characters in a string in get set. but whats the benefit of using classes in this way? to set default values? or something like that?

Comment: *to set default values* - exactly :)

Comment: @dendei: Implementing a singleton/lazy initialization as `return instance ?? instance = new Instance()` is never threadsafe. Two threads might access the property at the same time and each will get its own instance (while the second instance will be stored within the containing object).

Answer (score 1):

Use the constructor to initialize any properties that might not be set. That way you can still use an auto-property for `Rooms`:

```
public class Office {
    public long Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public long EmployesCount { get; set; }

    public Rooms Rooms { get; set; }

    public Office() {
      this.Rooms = new Rooms();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

from wat i percieve you are trying to do. An office can contain more then one room with different length and width so make a Room class whoes structure will be simillar to your Rooms class

```
public class Room
{
    public long Identifier { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    //and so on
}
```

and then in the office class make property as list of rooms

```
public class office
{
 public List<Room> Rooms{get; set;}
 public Office()
 {
  Rooms = new List<Room>()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two way. If you need to ensure that Rooms exist, then either use your code above or convert it back to an auto property

`public Rooms Rooms{ get; set; }`

and perform the initialization in the constructor.

Edit: If you are exposing the member then a property makes sense. If you are only using it in your class I would fall back to plain protected/private class member.

By the way. A classes called Rooms may indicate an issue here. A class is typically singular. When you wrap something I would suggest RoomCollection as wrapper class or simply IList or IEnumerable